# How to show Today, Tomorrow in place of date react native javascript

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I am showing a list of orders and it shows the date I want to show Today, Tomorrow instead of the date in the list.

Versions that I using.

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
```

For suppose today's date is `20 April 2021` and date in the list is `20 April 2021` it should show Today.

If the date in the list is `21 April 2021` but today's date is `20 April 2021` it should show Tomorrow in place of the date.

Date formate that i get from server   `'22 April, 2021'`

Answer (score 0):

According to [momentJS docs](https://momentjs.com/), you can use:

```
moment(date).fromNow()
```

It will show relative time.